# aws amazon-cloudwatch-agent - reopen log files on rotation

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2

As I understand, when amazon-cloudwatch-agent rotates a log file, my application needs to reopen the log file to start writing into a new file. How to implement this? Does amazon-cloudwatch-agent provies some hooks or signals for this purpose?

I looked for an answer to this question in amazon-cloudwatch-agent documentation and I haven't found anything about this topic

For example, logrotate provides a "postrotate" option for such purposes: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you are trying to do, sharing aws docs that may be useful to you: [Log retention and rotation defaults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managedservices/latest/userguide/log-defaults.html), [Manually create or edit the CloudWatch agent configuration file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html)

Comment: I need a possibility to run a command like in logrotate: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate (look at postrotate section)